# What kind of circuit or equipment do I need to use to amplify AC frquency?

Tags: frequency

I would like to convert 120V 60Hz to 120V 10kHz for induction cooking so I would need a frequency amplifier.

Comment: You need an induction heater drive.

Comment: what's a frequency amplifier?

Comment: I would convert the 120 60Hz to DC, and then feed that DC into a 10kHz chopper.   I have no idea how they actually do it, but in my head this totally would work  LOL  except you'd actually have like around 170VDC.   Season to taste

Comment: _I_ would get a stove that's already set up for induction cooking, unless your purpose is to try things out.

Comment: "frequency amplifier": not really an amplifier. You're just synthesizing a different frequency.

Comment: Useful search term : Royer oscillator (as others say, after rectifying and smoothing to DC)

Comment: @user_1818839 Royer oscillator or its modified version, Baxandall oscillator, can be a choice because of its simplicity but the frequency is input-voltage dependent. I don't know the tolerance of the requirement, though. Still can be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach to what you want would be:-

- Rectify and smooth the incoming AC to DC.
- Run an oscillator at the desired frequency.
- Use the oscillator to drive a high power driver, such as an H-bridge.

It gets more complicated if you want sine wave AC, rather than square wave.

Comment: Not much more complicated ... if anything, the usual Royer oscillator is a bit simpler and produces a reasonable sinusoid.